# OpenGeo Explorer for QGIS 2.6.1 - No module named ogr2ogrtopostgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, boundless-suite

I'm trying to use the OpenGeo Explorer plugin for QGIS (v2.6.1) to import shapefiles to my PostGIS database. I can connect to the server, but when I try to import, I get the following error:
No module named ogr2ogrtopostgis
I've been unable to find any reference to this module, or discussion of this error.

Windows 7

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the plugin (or plugin installer). Since the plugin is experimental, you probably should report that. Have you reported it?

Comment: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite-qgis-plugin/issues? should be the right target.

Comment: No, I'll go ahead and do so. I usually assume the fault lies with myself first, then look to the tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that my experience could be help you. 
In python console with QGIS 2.4 (import gdal and import ogr work.)
in QGIS 2.6.1 the same command give this errors:

> > > import gdal
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
> > >           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> > >       ImportError: No module named gdal

well the problem is in the sys.path og python! Infact is missing the path to ogr.py and gdal.py

sys.path present in QGIS 2.4 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\GDAL-1.11.0-py2.7-win32.egg'

in QGIS 2.6.1 is moved to 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo' !?!?

after

> > > sys.path.insert(1,'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo')

import gdal

import ogr

WORKS!!!!!!